# Pass Post Data To Get() - Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have`JobListView` in which im list the data as well displaying the form. Now when i am posting that i am directly redirected to same page. But now i want to filter out jobs query. So i need that posted data in `get()`. I am able to print `status` which is coming from `JobSearchForm` in `post()`. But not able to send that `status` in `get()`.

The reason i want to do this is that i want to filter out `jobs` query so that only particular list should be displayed. If you have any better approach then please suggest me.

```
class JobListView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.TemplateView):
    template_name = 'admin/jobs/job.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(JobListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        company_name = self.request.user.userprofile.user_company
        jobs = Jobs.objects.exclude(job_is_deleted = True).filter(job_company=self.request.user.userprofile.user_company)
        form = JobSearchForm()

        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form, 'jobs': jobs})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        form = JobSearchForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            status = form.cleaned_data['status']
            print (status)

        return HttpResponseRedirect('/useradmin/job/')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always better to use a get request to implement a search.
Also, you don't need a form I suppose.

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    context = super(JobListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    status = request.GET.get('status')
    company_name = self.request.user.userprofile.user_company
    jobs = Jobs.objects.exclude(job_is_deleted = True).filter(job_company=self.request.user.userprofile.user_company)
    if status:
        jobs.filter() # filter queryset using status
    return render(request, self.template_name, {'jobs': jobs})
```